# How to get time according to the offset provided by the user in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone, timezone-offset

I have been trying to convert time in google sheet cell according to the offset provided by the user. Here is an example:

> Cell A1(Current): 01:00 AM 
>  Cell A2(offset) : -5 
>  Cell
> A3(Desired): 08:00 PM

Is there any method using which we can convert cell A1 into cell A3? Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't it be wed 8pm?

Comment: No, I also want to move one day ahead.

Comment: The difference between thu 1am and fri 8pm is like 23 + 20 =43 hours

Comment: Actually it is about the offset. Let's say we don't have day condition. We just want to manipulate HH:MM (AM/PM).

Comment: Which are the cell "A1" and "A3" the date objects or the string values?

Comment: String values. Entered by the user.

Comment: @Roomi If you clear formatting, do the values align right or left? If it aligns right, they're date objects(even if it is entered by the user)

Comment: @TheMaster in that case, these values are left aligned.

Comment: Numeric values may be aligned left or right depending on the column alignment settings. Rather, I'd encourage you to type into some empty cell `=ISNUMBER(A1)` and report back whether you get TRUE or FALSE as a return.

Comment: @ErikTyler how can we use `=ISNUMBER(A1)` when we can clearly see that cell contains 01:00 AM in it.

Comment: Because `01:00 AM` may be a number formatted to show this way; or `01:00 AM` may be a text string. There is no way for us to know that unless you test it and tell us (or share the sheet).

Comment: I have tried your answer code, it creates time but not incorrect. Here is the sheet link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M1a3dzHXVF8GboKMftI3in-5r3c13iGLBXOm7aTYZzU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I edited the formula. I had a `-` where it needed a `+`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240043/discussion-between-roomi-and-erik-tyler).

Comment: About sharing spreadsheets, do note that [it exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). So, use a dummy Google account if you consider your email address to be private.

Comment: Sharing a spreadsheet *does not* expose your email address if you share your spreadsheet in "View only" or "Comment only" mode, only if you share it with full "Edit" permissions granted to anyone with the link. (I'll say it every time I see it.)

Comment: Hi @ErikTyler  You'll have better luck just adding a answer in the linked meta post. In any case, I think you're wrong. Share a spreadsheet with "anyone on the internet" comment/view only from a dummy Google account and I'll tell the email address, you're sharing from, within 30s(of reading your comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in A3:

`=TIMEVALUE(A1) + (A2/24)`

You will need to format A3 as *hh:mm am/pm*.

It's not clear why you need a script to accomplish this task. But if that is the case for some reason, I recommend that you add that reasoning to your post. Many users (particularly new ones) on this forum include the word "script" in their headlines or posts when they don't really know what one is, why they'd need one, or the difference between "script" and "formula"; so the volunteer contributors here will often provide the easiest/quickest route to the solution (which is the formula).